# pandas DataFrame.groupby and apply custom function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with many duplicates (I need Type/StrikePrice pair to be unique) like this:

```
                   Pos  AskPrice
Type  StrikePrice
C     1500.0       10    281.6
C     1500.0       11    281.9
C     1500.0       12    281.7     <- I need this one
P     1400.0       30    1200.5
P     1400.0       31    1250.2    <- I need this one
```

How can I group by `Type + StrikePrice` and apply some logic (my own function) to decide which row from the group to choose (let's say by the most greater `Pos`)

The expected result is

```
                   Pos  AskPrice
Type  StrikePrice
C     1500.0       12    281.7
P     1400.0       31    1250.2
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `reset_index` for unique indices, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of max values per groups and select rows by `loc`, last `set_index` for `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['Type','StrikePrice'])['Pos'].idxmax()]
       .set_index(['Type','StrikePrice'])
```

Or use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.reset_index()
       .sort_values(['Type','StrikePrice', 'Pos'])
       .drop_duplicates(['Type','StrikePrice'], keep='last')
       .set_index(['Type','StrikePrice']))
print (df)

                  Pos  AskPrice
Type StrikePrice               
C    1500.0        12     281.7
P    1400.0        31    1250.2
```

But if need custom function use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    return x[x['Pos'] == x['Pos'].max()]

df = df.groupby(level=[0,1], group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)
                  Pos  AskPrice
Type StrikePrice               
C    1500.0        12     281.7
P    1400.0        31    1250.2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great.